# Add SharpMap to Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: shapefile, .net, sharpmap

I have just installed Visual Studio 2008 and I want to add SharpMap or any other tool so that I can add a shapefile in .NET.

I have selected SharpMap because by the search I have discovered that SharpMap is good tool and it is opensource.

I have downloaded SharpMap from http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

Now I want to add this SharpMap to my Visual Studio 2008 so that I can add a shapefile to my project.

Any one can guide me step by step for this or is there any other good opensource tool will be welcomed for the betterment of the project?

Comment: Now sharpmap is available from nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/profiles/SharpMap-Team/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to [compile](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get%20SharpMap%20source%20code&referringTitle=How%20to...) SharpMap, then [add the proper references](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reference%20SharpMap&referringTitle=How%20to...) to your .NET project. From the [docs](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/documentation):

> In desktop applications add a reference to SharpMap.dll. For ASP.NET
>   web-applications place SharpMap.dll in the /bin/ folder.
>   Depending on the providers you intend to use, you may need to add a
>   reference to SharpMap.Extensions.dll. If you want/need to reproject
>   your data, you need to add ProjNet.dll as well.